# I got a question, jQuery.load or jQuery.ajax to load data of a database

Tags: jquery

I wonder which one will perform better.

thanks.

Comment: @jondavidjohn Any particular reason you reverted a distinct improvement to the question?

Comment: @lonesomeday the "distinct improvement" inferred the OP had a greater level of understanding of the topic then initially shown by the OP.

Comment: @jondavidjohn It also made it a *better* question, for the OP *and for future users*. But no matter.

Answer (score 3):

Well, they aren't alternatives...  They have different meanings, uses and purposes.

[`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax) is the all-purpose jQuery AJAX function.  All other AJAX functions use it, including `.load`.  If you want to do anything other than load a resource using AJAX, you have to write the code yourself.

[`.load`](http://api.jquery.com/load) uses `$.ajax` internally to get a resource, then loads that resource into the document, using the selection on which `load` was called.

If you want to do the latter, use `load`.  If you want to do anything else, use `$.ajax` or one of the other jQuery AJAX functions.